# Default relationship in many to many relationship ef core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have

- Contact Model which has IList property
- Group Model which has IList Property

There is 1 default group say "Default Group"
Now I want to insert this mapping to be added to table automatically whenever new contact is added.

I can add code to insert this relationship but looking for defaultvalue sort of thing if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you looking for does not exist. So, just add the necessary code and move on.

Comment: The attribute: [DefaultValue("Default Group")] or modelBuilder: .HasDefaultValue("Default Group")

Comment: @GHDevOps "modelBuilder: .HasDefaultValue("Default Group")" Does not work. tried. fails at migration